# How to setup detail/show pages for external database records in typo3?

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

I used a viewhelper to connect to my external database and insert the selected record in my fluid template. How can i now set up detail pages for those database records?

This is how i call the view helper in the fluid template

```
<f:for each="{mainnavigation}" as="mainnavigationItem">
    <f:if condition="{mainnavigationItem.active}">
        <f:for each="{mainnavigationItem.children}" as="child">
            <f:if condition="{child.active}">
                  <namespace:viewhelpername param1="{mainnavigationItem.title}" param2="{child.title}" />
            </f:if>
        </f:for>
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

The view helper now retrieves data from the database based on the parameters and adds a link for each database record to the html.

```
<a href="RECORD_ID">RECORD_TITLE</a>
```

Comment: Can I add some examples of your code?

Comment: I put some code in the question. I also thought of creating a hidden page in the typo3 backend and link the database records to this page and passing the record as a parameter, but i can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: In our projects we connect to external database in repository and build the object. Then in fluid all works like a records in TYPO3 database.